# Combining two clicky copies of the same record into one good recording

Tags: recording, signal-processing, isolation, vinyl, error

I have two copies of a Belgian 45 RPM single that are both rather clicky even after being washed. The pops occur throughout, stochastically, but occupy a small fraction of the overall time, such that the two copies together aren't missing any of the song. Having recorded the audio from each, I can imagine manually switching back and forth between them at 1/1000 speed to avoid all the clicks. What automated algorithm or method can produce a good recording from these sources?

EDIT: I will accept an explanation of why this is impossible as answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think you'd have a much simpler task if you tried some de-clicker software on the best of the pair than attempt to keep two independently-recorded analogue tracks in prefect phase-sync for three minutes whilst cross-cutting by eye.

I know of no software that could automate your chosen task.

My de-clicker of choice is [Waves X-Click](http://www.waves.com/plugins/x-click)
Two others I'm aware of but haven't used are [Sonnox Oxford](https://www.sonnox.com/plugin/oxford-declicker) & [Izotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx-plug-in-pack.html)

Comment: I agree that doing it manually is prohibitively difficult. Before that I would consider going back to spend yet more on a cleaner copy.

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that? ;) Cheaper than any of the plugins. I was thinking in purely 'engineering' terms, rather than stepping back from the problem.

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to achieve accurate phase sync across multiple plays of a vinyl disc.

Comment: @Mark, if the recordings were phase-aligned at the beginning, i'm not sure what would put them out of sync afterwards. the turntable has a heavy platter which ought to dampen variation in the mains power frequency.

Comment: @Tetsujin after looking in the marketplace the only easy option is a 20 euro compilation CD which includes this track. as you said,  a declicker is most practical... unless a good technical solution to this question appears.

Comment: With an analogue system with no accurate speed synch there is little to no chance that you would achieve phase alignment. Weight of platter will have no effect on mains power frequency whatsoever. They are totally unrelated.